# Apache mod_spdy - Enable/Disable per Virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, spdy

As the title suggests, i'm looking at mod_spdy and wondering if i can only enable it on certain VirtualHosts in apache, or if it's an 'all or nothing' kind of thing like PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the documentation doesn't say SpdyEnabled can't be used in a VHost definition, it appears to apply server-wide.

Answer (score 1):

> All of mod_spdy's configuration options begin with the prefix "Spdy", and most of them can be used either at the top level or within a VirtualHost context.

http://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/wiki/ConfigOptions

Yes, you can enable mod_spdy per VHost via: `SpdyEnabled on`